# DTD: 0, 1 or 2 Elements

Tags: xml, dtd

I need a DTD which allows an element A to have 0, 1 or 2 child-elements B. I tried it with

```
<!ELEMENT A (B? |(B,B))>
```

but then i get an error:

```
validity error : Content model of A is not determinist
```

what is the problem and how can i solve it? or isn't it possible to solve it with DTD?

Comment: Try this <!ELEMENT A (B?, B?)>

Comment: this was my first solution, but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content models such as

```
(B? |(B,B))
```

or

```
(B?, B?)
```

or

```
(B? | (B,B) | B)
```

are non-deterministic; the parser cannot tell which `B` is being matched without looking ahead to see what follows it.

Non-deterministic content models are disallowed in the XML 1.0 recommendation: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#determinism. However, the determinism requirement is there for compatibility with SGML. I guess that this may help in explaining differences in behaviour between XML parsers:

- xmllint (libxml2) is more "draconian" and reports all of the above content models as errors (*"Content model of A is not determinist"*).
- Xerces-J (the parser used in Oxygen, btw) presumably does not attempt to be compatible with SGML and accepts them.

See also: [What is the reason for not allowing non-deterministic element declarations in DTDs and XSD schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4523885/407651)

Answer (score 0):

Try this DTD to get desired XML:

```
<!ELEMENT A ((B?|(B,B)|B))>
<!ELEMENT B (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: I have checked this DTD and it is working fine in Oxygen. It has ability to support XML like <A></A>, <A><B/></A>, <A><B/><B/></A> as you required.